Can React Native WebRTC access video stream frames or capture screenshots? (react-native-view-shot produces a black screenshot)
I'm developing a mobile application using React Native, and I'm utilizing WebRTC (Web Real-Time Communication) for video streaming. My goal is to extract frames from the video stream and send them to a server for processing. However, I haven't found a suitable solution within React Native to achieve this.
As an alternative, I attempted to take screenshots of the video stream using the react-native-view-shot library. Unfortunately, the captured screenshots appear completely black, rather than showing the actual video content. This issue prevents me from sending the screenshots to the server for processing, as the images lack any useful information.
In essence, I'm seeking a reliable method to either:
Extract frames from the WebRTC video stream in React Native.
Capture screenshots of the video stream that accurately represent the video content.
A solution to either of these approaches would enable me to send the frames or screenshots to the server for further processing.
As an alternative, I attempted to take screenshots of the video stream using the react-native-view-shot library. Unfortunately, the captured screenshots appear completely black, rather than showing the actual video content. This issue prevents me from sending the screenshots to the server for processing, as the images lack any useful information.
In essence, I'm seeking a reliable method to either:
Extract frames from the WebRTC video stream in React Native.
Capture screenshots of the video stream that accurately represent the video content.
A solution to either of these approaches would enable me to send the frames or screenshots to the server for further processing.
